# v-binding an image from an object to an img src not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to bind an object's URL dinamically to my component, but it is not working. It only works if I use require and if I link it directly, as following: `"v-bind:imagem="/home/thalys/Documentos/Dev/CodeX/santuarioec/src/imgs/anuncio.png""`, or if I put the relative path, like `'../imgs/anuncio.png'` or `'@/imgs/anuncio.png'`.

```
<template>
   <div>
      <site-template>
         <div class="anuncio">
            <anuncio v-for="anuncio in anuncios" v-bind:key="anuncio.id" v-bind:imagem="anuncio.imagem">

            </anuncio>
         </div>

      </site-template>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import SiteTemplate from '@/templates/SiteTemplate'
import Anuncio from '@/components/anuncio/Anuncio'

export default {
    name: 'Home',
    components: {
       SiteTemplate,
       Anuncio
    },
    data () {
       return {
          anuncios: [
             { "id": 1, "imagem": "/home/thalys/Documentos/Dev/CodeX/santuarioec/src/imgs/anuncio.png" },
             { "id": 2, "imagem": "/home/thalys/Documentos/Dev/CodeX/santuarioec/src/imgs/anuncio.png" },
             { "id": 3, "imagem": "/home/thalys/Documentos/Dev/CodeX/santuarioec/src/imgs/anuncio.png" },
             { "id": 4, "imagem": "/home/thalys/Documentos/Dev/CodeX/santuarioec/src/imgs/anuncio.png" },
             { "id": 5, "imagem": "/home/thalys/Documentos/Dev/CodeX/santuarioec/src/imgs/anuncio.png" }
          ]
       }
    }
 }
 </script>
```

And here is my component "Anuncio"

```
<template>
    <div class="anuncio">
        <div class="w3">                
          <img class="img" v-bind:src="imagem"/>
       </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Anuncio',
    props: ['titulo', 'imagem'],
    data () {
        return {
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: What is the complete path to your project?

Comment: /home/thalys/Documentos/Dev/CodeX/santuarioec

Comment: I moved my "imgs" folder to assets, just like the guy down here told me. Then I tried to do as you told me, but it didnt worked either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the solution:

In your `Anuncio` component you have to hardcode the path to your images into the `require()` 
method. So your `img` HTML-Tag would look like follwing:

```
<img class="img" v-bind:src="require(`../imgs/${imagem}`)"/>
```

In the Array which contains the pathes with the names of the images you should just provide the names and the `.png`.
It would look like this:

```
anuncios: [
             { "id": 1, "imagem": "anuncio.png" },
             { "id": 2, "imagem": "anuncio.png" },
             { "id": 3, "imagem": "anuncio.png" },
             { "id": 4, "imagem": "anuncio.png" },
             { "id": 5, "imagem": "anuncio.png" }
          ]
```

Try it out.

Comment: Thanks duude, thank you so much! I only needed to make some changes on the solution you gave. I left my "Anuncio" component with only <img class="img" v-bind:src="imagem" /> and did what you said in my home page:
<anuncio v-for="anuncio in anuncios" v-bind:key="anuncio.id" v-bind:titulo="anuncio.id" v-bind:imagem="require(`../assets/imgs/${anuncio.imagem}`)">

Comment: Yeeaah! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

There should be an assets folder in your `/src` directory if you've initiated your project with `vue-cli` (https://cli.vuejs.org/).

Move your `imgs` folder into the assets folder. Rewrite your image path to `@/assets/imgs/anuncio.png` (no `require()` required).

Comment: I did as you told me, but it still doesnt work. Any other solution?